# Page not found or redirect?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, seo

My rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^articles/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?page=articles&cat=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^articles/([a-z]+)/?$ /index.php?page=articles&cat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

So, in index.php file, i check for existence of `page`. If it is found, that page is echoed. Otherwise, what to do ?

- Send a redirect to home page ?
- Send 404 page not found response using header() ?
- Echo a message like "Page Not Found" ?

Which one is good? I want to know search engine friendly option among these.

Comment: SEO is not really programming related.

Comment: thanku. so where should i post seo related questions ?

Comment: [Webmasters.SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: there are 2233 questions tagged under SEO in SE !! so it looks like seo related questions were posted plenty in here. Do i have to post other questions in WSE ?

Comment: It depends on the actual question: Questions like *What is better with SEO in mind?* are not programming related while questions like *How can I implement this SEO measure?* are programming related.

Comment: May I know why I got a negative mark for this question ?
So that it will be help me to avoid doing that mistake again.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121350/ive-just-been-down-voted-how-should-i-react-to-this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely have a header() which returns the proper 404 error code. This will ensure that google does not index your error page. Serving a standard page with a message without the 404 code is called a soft 404 error, and is discouraged by the standards (and by google).

See here: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=181708

But it is not necessary to show an ugly text-only error to your visitor, or rely on his browser's default error page. Even if you output a 404 code, you can still serve a beautiful page, maybe with a link to your home page, or with relevant resources.

Comment: thanku. You mean, i should place a customized 404 page and set it as the default error page to popup when a 404 header is sent ? Like this: `header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");` ?

Comment: It depends on how your content management system works. But in principle, you send a 404 header, then you include your error page and exit...

Comment: i have separated my page header(common), page footer(common) and the page content into each. So, i should check if page exists. If not, echo page header, then page content will be 404 page not found(custom message), then finally echo the page footer. Is it so ? But that would index that page in google. Isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, it's like you said. If you output the 404 header google will not index your page. That is exactly the point of that header: to show to the machines that this is not a page but an error. The content of the page, on the other hand, is for your human visitors.

Comment: One important point is to return a 404 error on the original page, instead of redirecting to an error page.

Answer (score 1):

**In precedence**

> - Send a 404 page not found response using header() ?(hard 404)
>
> Which is ideal as the page was literally not found.
>
> - Echo a message like "Page Not Found" ? (soft 404)
>
> This is fine as you are trying to find the page internally but not exactly ideal.

**Do not do a:**

> - Send a redirect to home page ?
>
>   As this does not portray any information like,
>
>   - whether the page was not found.
>   - was there any internal error.
>       etc.

Go through this: [404 errors soft vs. hard](http://www.gravitateonline.com/learn-seo/traditional-404-errors-vs-soft-404-errors) you will get the idea.

Comment: thanku. If a user goes to `www.mysite.com/hello`, this page does not exists. So, i echo a message like "Page Not Found". But this will be indexed by google. Correct ?

Comment: @VppMan Yes . It will be indexed by google. It is better to do a hard 404. not a soft 404 even though google indexes it. You can place a customized 404 error page for your hard 404's.

Comment: thanku. If i create a custom 404 page, how to use it in PHP ? Send a redirect to that page ? Or is there a setting that I can change in the server configuration ?

Comment: @VppMan I presume you are using apache. in apache's `.conf` file, there is setting `ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html` change the `/missing.html` to you custom page. Just specify the path here.

Comment: thanku. After I setup my custom page, this is the code i should use to send the 404 error: `header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");`. Correct ?

Comment: I have tried both: `header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");` and `header("Status: 404 Not Found");`First one gives `Oops! This link appears to be broken.` in Chrome and second one gives blank white page !

Comment: yes. I was using the line from that manual. I have edited httpd.conf file an included the path of error document as: `ErrorDocument 404 http://mysite/404.html` (WAMP - Virtual Host)

Comment: I checked access log and the last two lines are: `127.0.0.1 - - [04/Feb/2012:23:20:28 +0530] "GET /asdsfddfdsss HTTP/1.1" 404 -` and 
`127.0.0.1 - - [04/Feb/2012:23:20:28 +0530] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 302 210`

Comment: @VppMan Its should not be a protocol `http://` it should be a system path. Like `/mysite/myerrorpage.html`

Comment: I have also tried appending this in htaccess file of my site:`ErrorDocument 404 404.html` (404.html resides in root of my site).

Comment: @VppMan If 404.html resides in the `DocumentRoot` of your site then give the path '/404.html' not just `404.html`

Comment: I have also tried uploading it to my Hostgator account. Then created a 404 page using cPanel and set it as the default 404page. But when I tested, it gives "Oops! This link appears to be broken." in Chrome and blank screen in Firefox ! Can you please test it in ur side. Thanku